# Upgraded to core 3.0 and now my Service Fabric builds fail with FabActUtil error

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I've read through all the posts and articles I can find, but I am still struggling to get my Actors building. As the title indicates, I've upgraded my app from .net core 2.2.7 to 3.0 and now the actors in my solution fail to build. The exact error is:

```
    error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "obj\\FabActUtilTemp\FabActUtil.dll" 
/spp:"PackageRoot" /t:manifest /sp:"[ProjectName]" /in:"bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win7-x64\\[ProjectName].dll" /arp:
"[ProjectPath]\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\win7-x64\\" /smep:Exe " exited with code
-2147450749. [ProjectPath].csproj]
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Hello, did you find out? I upgraded my service fabric to .NET Core 3.0 and it seems to be failing as well

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same issue today, there are some possible reasons for this [ticket293](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/293), [ticket150](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/issues/150).

Please make sure your projects are using the same latest version of service fabric libraries, e.g. Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors, and after updating the libraries, some break changes can be involved. Resolving the break changes (probably hence build errors) and run a clean build.